# Azure upload blob failed after 15 minutes

Tags: c#, upload, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using DataMovement library to upload a file to an Azure Storage account.
The blob size is 96MB.

If the connection is slow every time after 15 minutes the upload failed with error:
**One or more errors occurred. (The transfer failed.)**

My code:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(sConnString));
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 10;
...
var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(pathFile, blockBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None);                
task.Wait();
```

How can I solve it? Why 15 minutes?

Error StackTrace:

```
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at TeamSystem.Enterprise.Cloud.Migrator.Engine.CloudServices.UploadFile(String pathFile, String blobName, Boolean testMode) in C:\EnterpriseCloud\Migrator\TeamSystem.Enterprise.Cloud.Migrator.Engine\Code\CloudServices.cs:line 86
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please add the exception that was raised, there is some guidance for this issue in the github issues on this product as well: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues/174

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT sure... I've edited above.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution! The problem was in "TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations" property.

Trying to decrease that value from 64 to 2 in case of slow connection I haven't the issue.

So I've created a function like this for stimate "ParallelOperations" from connection speed:

```
private int GetParallelOperations(double transfertSpeed)
        {
            int retval = 0;
            switch (transfertSpeed)
            {
                case double n when (n >= 1):
                    retval = Environment.ProcessorCount * 8;
                    break;
                case double n when (n < 1 && n>=0.1):
                    retval = 10;
                    break;                
                default:
                    retval = 2;
                    break;
            }

            return retval;
        }
```

And then:

```
TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = GetParallelOperations(Utilities.TransferSpeed);
```

where transfer speed is stimated with a simple file with size 5MB. For speed test I left "ParallelOperations" set to "Environment.ProcessorCount * 8" (works also in case of slow connection).

Comment: What is the transfer speed unit of measure? I kind of uploaded 600Mb file with speed of 40kbps and after half an hour it failed. It was multiple files. Any suggestions? I set the parallel operations to 2.